Which commit is my staging slot using after a swap?
Let's say I have a pipeline that deploys to my staging slot in Azure Web Apps. Then I swap staging into production. Is my staging slot now on the previous deployment commit? e.g.

Production slot is running commit 9
Commit 10 to 'staging' branch
Pipeline runs, staging slot is now running commit 10
Swap staging into production
Production is now running commit 10

Is staging running commit 9? Do I have to re-run the deployment to staging at this point to get it to commit 10?

Yes, when you perform a slot swap, the following would happen in this scenario:

Your production slot will be running commit 10 (the new deployment).
Your staging slot will be running commit 9 (which was previously in production).

So, after the swap, your staging slot will indeed be running the older commit (commit 9). To ensure that both slots are running the same version (commit 10), you would need to re-deploy commit 10 to the staging slot after the swap. The documentation hints at this behavior:

Continuous deployment should never be enabled for your production slot. Instead, your production branch (often main) should be deployed onto a nonproduction slot. When you're ready to release the base branch, swap it into the production slot. Swapping into production—instead of deploying to production—prevents downtime and allows you to roll back the changes by swapping again.

